# Postgresql: Generated column as output from a function

Tags: postgresql, generated-columns

I was trying to create a generated column. It should be output of some function with parameter as one of its column, e.g. **custom_function(column1)**.
where custom_function is a user defined function of postgresql
and column1 is any column of the table.
Actual query is as below-

```
ALTER TABLE ttt.test
    ADD COLUMN "checkDigit" char GENERATED ALWAYS AS (ttt.getfunction(actual_sn)) STORED;
```

But getting error 'ERROR: generation expression is not immutable'

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: your generation expression (`ttt.getfunction(actual_sn)`) is not [immutable](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html). If your function is immutable, mark it as such. If it's not, you may need to consider a different solution.

Comment: @NickBarnes: Thanks for your quick reply. It worked after making the function IMMUTABLE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It worked after making the function(ttt.getfunction) IMMUTABLE.